# Run python script on SQL trigger

Tags: python, sql, triggers, arcgis

I have a python script that updates fields through the ArcGis REST API, and it works fine. Now I want to run this script every time a new row is inserted into the database.

When the user makes a new entry in the database only fieldA and fieldB is filled out, the rest is null, and fields C to E is filled by the python script witch takes the OBJECTID as input.

From google I made this, and it seems to works, except I think it enters a endless loop.

```
USE [Test]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tgr_point] 
   ON   [dbo].[POINTOBS]
   AFTER INSERT
 AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NUMBER as varchar(8000) 
    Declare @Cmd as varchar(8000) 
    Declare @Cmd2 as varchar(8000) 
    SET @NUMBER =(SELECT [OBJECTID] FROM INSERTED)
    SET @CMD = 'C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.2\python.exe C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.2\model_6.py '
    SET @CMD2 = @CMD + @NUMBER
    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @CMD2

END
```

I think maybe a solution is to trigger only when something is inserted into fieldA, but I could not find a code that worked for me.
(Running SQL Server 2016)